# MYSQL equivalent query in Django Average and Group By

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, mysql-python

Please help me to write the same query in Django using ORM

```
SELECT DATE(`created_at`) DateOnly, 
AVG(`amout`) AS val_1  
FROM `account`  
GROUP BY DateOnly
```

Comment: At a guess: `for p in account.objects.raw('SELECT DATE(created_at) DateOnly, AVG(amout) AS val_1 FROM account GROUP BY DateOnly'): ...     print(p)` - Note that `amout` isn't a word

Comment: @Strawberry I'm looking for ORM not raw query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the `datetime` to `date` using **[`Cast`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#cast)** and then aggregate using **[`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values)**. A common idiom in ORM `.values().annotate(..)` is used to perform `group by` operation.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import DateField

Account.objects.annotate(
   DateOnly = Cast('created_at', output_field=DateField()),
).values('DateOnly').annotate(val_1 = Avg('amout'))
```